# How to map an array to another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm so confused with arrays. Can any one help me to solve this??
I have 4 arrays, these all are related.

My array structure is like:

```
Array 1:
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 [5] => 1 )
Array 2:
Array ( [0] => 500 [1] => 500 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 3 [5] => 3 )
Array 3:
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 [5] => 1 )
Array 4:
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 [5] => 1 )
```

I have to map all 1 value from Array 1 to another arrays.

Comment: What is the output structure?

Comment: i have fetch all unique values from array 1 and map to the coressponding positions of other arrays

Comment: first value 1 fetches corresponding 500,2,1 of other arrays ,like this all 1 of array 1 fetches its corresponding of others

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map the values of 4 arrays to each position, you can:

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1 );
$arr2 = array(500, 500, 1, 2, 3, 3 );
$arr3 = array(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1 );
$arr4 = array(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1 );

$results = array_map(function($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4) {
    return array($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4);
}, $arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $results );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 500
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 500
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

)
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php